# Subcategory work as a default categories when is anchor property set to yes

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In magento when we set is anchor property Yes the subcategories are converted into filters & also shows other filters like Price, Color & Special price.

I set Is Anchor property Yes in all categories & here I want to do is subcategories will open with default category URL.

I do not make Is anchor property No because I want to show other filters also like price, color & sub categories.

Please help me to do this modification.

Comment: Please anyone can please suggest me correct steps to apply this function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a view possible mistakes:

- Maybe you have to reindex your attributes, flat category table and
  flat product table.
- Please make sure you're caches are disabled.
- Make sure you use the right template, with sidebar.
- Maybe the categorie isn't filled with any enabled products with stock.

...